# How can we have two SplitterView in same view in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I want to have to two splitterViews in iPad's view. I would like to use same nib files for the two splitterViews and then populate them accordingly.

One of the approach could be that I have two separate nib files, root view controllers for two views but that will increase redundancy.

I even tried to use single splitter views in two frames using following logic in viewdidload(), but that does not works.

```
[splitViewControllerCategory.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150, 500, 1024)];

[self.view addSubview:splitViewControllerCategory.view];

[splitViewControllerSortMedia.view setFrame:CGRectMake(500,150, 265, 1024)];

[self.view addSubview:splitViewControllerSortMedia.view];
```

Any suggestions to approach the solution.

Comment: why u have to need this type of work ??

Comment: the main view has two split views with two different root view controllers based on business logic as per the requirement.